# Configure touch pen on gnome

Tags: configuration, touchscreen, pencil

I've just bought a touch pen, it's one of those with a battery inside, doesn't pair via bluetooth. It's simply turned on or off and, when it's on, it should work on a touchscreen.
It works flawlessly on my android phone, but I can't say the same when using it on my gnome, as you can see:[image: touch pen test on xournal++]

These should be straight lines.
When I use my fingers, I get a much better result.

Is there any configuration I can do on my pc so to make the pen work smoothly as it is on my phone...?

Comment: Do you get the same results in all the apps? Also, which version of Ubuntu? Can you post the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?